# Is this statement true? (Cyclic Group)

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group.
>
> Let $a$ be an element of $G$ such that $a\neq e$.
>
> If there exists $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $a^m=e$, then $G$ is finite.

Is this true?

Moreover, is $\{e\}$ the only finite subgroup of an infinite cyclic group?

Comment: Do you know that the only infinite cyclic group is $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Seth Yeah i know that any infinite cyclic group is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the only infinite cyclic group is $\mathbb{Z}$.  How many elements does $\mathbb{Z}$ have of finite order?

Comment: Strictly speaking, up to isomorphism.